# Обратиться к открытому процессу (process)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, процесс

Как обратиться к уже запущенному на компьютере процессу, прочитать линию или подать новую команду.
Допустим на компьютере запущен Process.

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\[PathFolder]";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K index";            
        process.Start();

        process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"Hello World!");
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
```

В этом месте все работает, и мы получаем строку. Мы можем так же подать следующею команду.

```
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"Hello World 2019!");
```

Но как допустим из акции контроллера прочитать строку или подать новую команду этому процессу. Первая строка правильно получает сам процесс и можно вывести его Id.

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {      

        Process proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("index").FirstOrDefault();
        ViewData["Message"] = proc.Id;
        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"Hello World!");
        ViewData["MessageTwo"] = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        return View();
    }
```

Но при попытки прочитать или передать.
В моем случае получаем ошибку, в зависимости от операции.

```
StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet.
```

или

```
StandardIn has not been redirected.
```

Что сделано не так?

Comment: А попробуйте в action тоже проставить proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandard* = true. Хотя вряд ли сработает, ведь вывод уже прошел в output до этого перенаправления

Comment: Да, я это пробовал ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Имхо не выйдет так перенаправить уже после запуска стороннего процесса (если он запущен не из процесса откуда вы его пытаетесь прочитать). А значит IPC. А если чужой процесс нельзя подправить под свои нужды, то сделать враппер над консолью с IPC

Comment: `pipe` или `socket` вам в помощь